# Trying to pass Array from Server Side to be read from Javascript in my MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Any help much appreciated, not sure why this is not working, in my server side code i have:

```
foreach (var item in Model)
               {
                   if (item.SiteLocation == null || item.SiteLocation.SiteLocationId == 0)
                   { }
                   else
                   {

                       if ((item.SiteLocation.Latitude != 0) && (item.SiteLocation.Longitude != 0))
                           Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("Sites", "'" + item.SiteId + "','" + item.SiteDescription + "','" + item.SiteLocation.Longitude + "','" + item.SiteLocation.Latitude + "'");
                   }
```

...........then i try to reference the array using the following code in Javascript :

```
    for (var i = 0; i < Sites.length; i++) {
        // Create and Element Object of type "option"
        alert(Sites[i]);
    }
```

..........but it says "Sites is undefined"

I've debugged server side and the "Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration" line runs a few times so no idea why object is not there when i use the Javascript, any ideas?

Comment: Thanks Adrian, i've went over my previous posts and flagged as answered,cheers, J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration`?
2. In an ASP.NET MVC application?
3. Are you serious?

In an ASP.NET MVC application you use controller action which return ActionResults. So you could return JSON:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    return Json(new[] { "elem1", "elem2" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then you could consume this controller action using AJAX for example.

Another possibility is to have this array as a property of your view model:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel 
    {
        SomeArray = new[] { "elem1", "elem2" }
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and then serialize this property in the view using [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myArray = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.SomeArray) %>;
    // TODO: now you can use the array as a native javascript object
</script>
```

Comment: I 100% second this answer.  @John: Remember that in MVC, the "code-behind" has no connection to the View other than the model that it passes in to it.. As a matter of fact, there is no such thing as code-behind in MVC, unless you actually add a webforms-page to your app...

Comment: I could only add comments to this but needed to supply more info. Thanks for the help Darin, are you able to view this link if you have a spare minute, mayn thanks, j

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345281/add-an-array-object-as-a-property-of-my-existing-controller-class-method